# How to protect PDF and MP4 inside iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, pdf, encryption

I have this requirement, to download pdf/video file into the iOS/Android phone. then user can read offline.

Since the data now rest inside the app, how to prevent people from accessing and copy the file ?

### EDIT

1. I know we can put password protected inside the PDF, and hardcode the password when we want to open it. but, How about video ?
2. second way, to encrypt/decrypt it. Can someone brief on this ? how to get this done ? possible issue, performance issue, since video contain big file size.

Comment: In smart card, I use a master key that encrypts everything and then stores into persistence memory. When ever an authenticated entity try to use any data, I decrypt it first then send it to that entity. But any unauthenticated entity only gets the garbage form of the data. If any security threat occurs, I just erase the key, hence make my data secured. May be this concept helps you.

Comment: But for iOS, is there a way to extract the file inside the app ?

Comment: why not using sha256 or AES?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin SHA256 is not encryption, it is a hash function.

Comment: Both the PDF and video could be encrypted on the server with a key shared with the app and decrypted as needed on the app.